# How to read a fixed amount of data(ex.30KB) from pyserial

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to read from a serial port until some KB(ex.10KB), after that I should stop writing to file and check a string. I have tried this in the code below but it doesn't work for me. It always saves only 5KB, saved log is nothing but line 1 to 8.

```
rs232.write(parser.get('values', 'flash') + '\r\n')

print "Check"
filename = 'test.txt'
file1 = parser.get('values', 'LOG_PATH') + filename
text_file = open(file1, 'w+')

cond = True

while cond:
    x = rs232.read(10000)
    text_file.write(x)
    for line in open(file1, 'r'):
        if not line.startswith("[FIT]"):
            cond = False
```

Thanks for the answers, I would like to update my question, **I should read my serial port for 5mins to check the string**(**"[FIT]"**), if string not found in 5mins I should send "reboot" command to serial port, if string found my program should continue..This is where I am stuck...Can someone help with this...Sorry if my previous post is miss guiding you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you are not setting a timeout when you create the serial.Serial object. According to [the serial.Serial.read() documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read):

> Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.

If you have a timeout set and really need it due to unreliable serial sources, consider increasing it to allow more time to read the number of bytes you're requesting. Also, you should be specifying the size as a keyword argument like my example below.

BTW, you may also be having issues because of how you're opening your files. You're opening **file1** in write+ mode, then opening it again in read-only. I would suggest something more like this:

```
rs232.write(parser.get('values', 'flash') + '\r\n')

print "Check"
filename = 'test.txt'
file1 = parser.get('values', 'LOG_PATH') + filename

while True:

    x = rs232.read(size=10000) # change this to a keyword argument
    with open(file1, 'w+') as fo:
        fo.write(x)

    # no need to read the file back in - we already have the data in memory
    # we will just decode the bytes object and split it on the newlines, then
    # iterate over them

    if any((line.startswith("[FIT]") for line in x.decode("utf-8").split('\n'))):
        break
```

If you insist on reading the file back in instead, use this after writing out X:

```
with open(file1, 'r') as fi:
    if any((line.startswith("[FIT]") for line in fi)):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should decrease the value of read, you are expecting 10000 bytes,what if you expect only one and keep the counting on another variable?. I'm assuming you are sure that the other part is sending at least that ammount of data.

```
while true:
    x = rs232.read(1)
    total_string += x
    if [k for k in total_string.split("\n") if k.starstwith("[FIT]")]:
        break
    if not x and total_string:
        #dump to file
        # Empty the total_string to avoid duplicates in the file dump.
        total_string = ""
        continue
```